# How can I interact with Rserve through PHP on a LAMP system?

Tags: php, r, lamp, rserve

I am trying to execute a PHP file that interacts with Rserve on a LAMP system. The PHP file is located in the public_html directory on the server. Rserve is installed and running in Rserve's default directory within R `(/usr/lib64/R/library/Rserve).` Is there a particular folder the PHP files need to be in for a proper connection to Rserve? Do I need to use a remote connection when both Rserve and the PHP files are on the same server?

The PHP file returns this error: `No path specified.Invalid response from server.Connect FAILED`

Sample PHP-Rserve test file:

```
<?php
require_once 'simple.php';
$s = Rserve_connect();
if ($s == FALSE) {
     echo "Connect FAILED";
} else {
     print_r (Rserve_eval($s, "list(str=R.version.string,foo=1:10,bar=1:5/2,logic=c(TRUE,FALSE,NA))"));
 echo "<p/>";
     print_r (Rserve_eval($s, "{x=rnorm(10); y=x+rnorm(10)/2; lm(y~x)}"));
 Rserve_close($s);
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Telnet result:

```
#telnet 127.0.0.1 6311
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Rsrv0103QAP1
```

Process Result:

```
# ps ax|grep Rserve
14028 ?      Ss  0:00  /usr/lib64/R/bin/Rserve
15264 pts/3  S+  0:00  grep Rserve
```

Comment: This isn't clear. Does the PHP work? If not, how not? What's that 'telnet result' and 'process result' meant to show us? RServe doesn't care where your PHP files are, but your web server will. So... uh, what's not working?

Comment: I have edited the question. The PHP script does not work. The error is shown above. The 'telnet result' and 'process result' shows that Rserve is running and accessible on 'localhost' (127.0.0.1).

Comment: Assuming simple.php is the file supplied with Rserve, have you edited it correctly, because its not really meant to be used exactly like that. Are you following some documentation somewhere?

Comment: simple.php is the file supplied with Rserve. I have not altered the file. I was using the testing portion of simple.php at the bottom of the file. `/*========== user code -- example and test -- comment out the above and uncomment this for testing`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465768/how-to-use-rserve-usage-with-php

Answer (score 0):

i think you would need to pass host and port params to connect. example

```
Rserve_connect( localhost, 6311)
```